# Sorting NULL Fields in the ORDER BY FIELD command (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, database

We are selecting a few fields from a database (including a left join) and have managed to order them by a field containing an INT using this command:

```
ORDER BY FIELD (t.type, '1','2','4','5','3')
```

That's the order they appear, however we also have entries that contain no integers, they are retuning as NULL. That's fine, but we can't seem to place the NULL entries where we want them.

We want them second in the list, for example:

```
ORDER BY FIELD (t.type, '1','NULL','2','4','5','3')
```

or

```
ORDER BY FIELD (t.type, '1','0','2','4','5','3')
```

etc...

How can we achieve this and place the entries with a NULL t.type field second in the list?

I've been searching high and low since posting this message but can't find anything on the topic.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:

Here is the full select statement we are using:

```
select d.url, d.lid, d.title, d.description, d.date, d.hits, d.downloadratingsummary, d.totalvotes, d.totalcomments, d.filesize, d.version, d.homepage, d.ns_compat, d.ns_des_img, t.type from downloads_downloads d LEFT JOIN downloads_type t on d.lid = t.lid where cid=96 ORDER BY FIELD (t.type, 1,12,2,4,5,3), d.date DESC LIMIT 0,20
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is there a value you can substitute for NULL that doesn't appear anywhere else?  Something like:

```
ORDER BY FIELD(coalesce(t.type, -1), '1', '-1', '2', '4', '5', '3')
```

By the way, the arguments can also be numbers instead of strings:

```
ORDER BY FIELD(coalesce(t.type, -1), 1, -1, 2, 4, 5, 3)
```

Comment: This works brilliantly, thank you very much for posting a solution.  We have used -1 as you suggested.  Are there any major performance disadvantages of this method?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes around `NULL`. It's not a string. In fact, remove the quotes around the numbers as well. They probably don't hurt in that case, but they're also not strings.

If that doesn't work, I'm not sure how to properly handle it. The [MySQL doc for FIELD()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field) says:

> If str is NULL, the return value is 0 because NULL fails equality comparison with any value.

So, as you tried in your third example, you might have to use 0, but perhaps removing the quotes will fix it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however this command "ORDER BY FIELD (t.type, '1,NULL,2,4,5,3')" still returns NULLS first.  Any ideas on how to make NULLS return second in the list?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sounds like you found your answer, but just to clarify, the example in your comment above makes the entire series one long string. I meant to do this: `ORDER BY FIELD(t.type, 1, NULL, 2, 4, 5, 3)` (note that there are no quotes at all here).

Answer (score 0):

why not do this in your SELECT statement something like
    SELECT IFNULL(t.type, 2)
    FROM table_name t

Here you are assigning the value of 2 to any NULL values.  Does this work for you?

Comment: We tried this method, but it results in a seperate column called "SELECT IFNULL(t.type, 2)" - perhaps we didn't write the syntax correctly.  Thank you for your help anyway, a working solution was answered above.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 ORDER BY CASE `t.type` 
            WHEN '1' THEN 1
            WHEN '2' THEN 2
            WHEN '4' THEN 3
            WHEN '5' THEN 4
            WHEN '3' THEN 5
            WHEN null THEN 6
         END
```